# I want to place a script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

gatsby.js v4.4.0

I want to set up a script tag.
However, I get an error and cannot set it up.

Please tell me how to install it.

```
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
```

The error code will be displayed in your browser.

> Error in function customElements.define.extends.load in
> x-frame-bypass.js: X-Frame-Bypass src does not start with http(s)://
>
> x-frame-bypass.js:  No codeFrame could be generated

html.js

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}

html.js
```

Comment: uh, what's your question? please provide some more info.

Comment: I want to install a script tag.
However, I get an error and cannot install it.

Please tell me how to install it.

Comment: you shouldn't have an html tag in react, ut will be put in the `root` div in the body. instead add the scripts in index.html

Comment: I added it to html.js.
However, I got an error like the one in the text.

Comment: what props are being passed to HTML?

Comment: maybe Helmet value

Comment: Looks like it's x-frame-bypass's error, which means you loaded the script succesfully.

Comment: Oh brother :) I think you should keep English tho, it's StackOverflow after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you shouldn't have an html tag in react

Agree, however, in this case, he's using [HTML customization of Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/).

The error that is being prompted:

> Error in function customElements.define.extends.load in
> x-frame-bypass.js: X-Frame-Bypass src does not start with http(s)://
>
> x-frame-bypass.js: No codeFrame could be generated

This means that the script is loaded successfully.

If you take a look to the URL you are requesting (https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass@1.0.2/x-frame-bypass.js) you'll see the `customElements.define` and the exception that is being thrown at:

```
if (!url || !url.startsWith('http'))
    throw new Error(`X-Frame-Bypass src ${url} does not start with http(s)://`)
console.log('X-Frame-Bypass loading:', URL)
```

This is likely to be a `localhost` issue. It should be gone as soon as the site is deployed to a custom domain.

In addition, according to the [docs](https://unpkg.com/browse/x-frame-bypass@1.0.2/README.md), the order of the scripts should be inverted:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
```

The first (optional) one is:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
```

Once done, you only need to load the `iframe` with the `is="x-frame-bypass"` attribute:

```
<iframe
    is="x-frame-bypass"
    src="https://stackoverflow.com/"
    height="100%"
    width-"100%"
 />
```

Comment: Thank you ferran. So it can't be run in a local environment? I would upload it to the server and then check.

I want to upload it to cloudflare pages.
I am not sure if I can upload with this error.

Comment: I'm not sure what this script is doing but I guess it's throwing the exception because the URL is not valid. If it doesn't allow you to upload the project with this error, try adding a condition to add the script or use the `Helmet` component in any other component

Comment: https://5c806958.surprise-movie.pages.dev/posts/attempted-robbery-goes-bad-for-both-parties　Finally, I was able to deploy the site. However.
I don't think the iframe x-frame-bypass has any effect.

I filled in html.js.